# Use spherical coordinates to evaluate

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Use spherical coordinates to evaluate

$\int_{-2} ^{2} \int_0 ^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} ^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} dz \ dx \ dy$

I did like this. Is that right ?

$$\int_0 ^\pi \int_0 ^\pi \int_0 ^2 p^2\sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta\cdot p\cdot p^2\sin \phi \ dp \ d \phi \ d \theta  $$

Thanks.

Comment: $\theta$ should be from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta$ should be from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, since you have the right half of the circle in the $xy$-plane. To see this, the region is

> $$ 0\leq x \leq \sqrt{4-y^2},\quad -2\leq y \leq 2. $$

So, plot this region and you will see what's going on.

Comment: Ohh I understand that ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Ewin: You are very welcome.